# Entity Framework 6, existing Database. Related data but no Navigation property. I'm lost

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a project with an existing databse. Didn't really have any problems until now as I can't understand how I could possibly write this query.

I have two Entities:

Contactperson.cs

```
public class ContactPerson
{
    public Guid ContactPersonID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
    public string StreetAndNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

ClientContactPerson.cs

```
public class ClientContactPerson
{
    public Guid ClientID { get; set; }
    public Guid ContactPersonID { get; set; }
    public int? RelationshipID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual Client { get; set; }
}
```

On Client.cs the only relation to ClientContactPerson is this:

```
public virtual ICollection<KlientKontaktperson> KlientKontaktperson { get; set; }
```

Now, what I need to query is, I pass the ClientID to the controller:

```
public JsonResult GetContactperson(Guid Id)
{

    var ContactQuery = db.ClientContactPerson.Where(i => i.ClientID == Id).ToList();

    var contactperson = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ContactpersonDto>>(contactpersonQuery);

    return Json(kontaktperson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now my JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "ClientContactPerson": "e5b05f3a-4fa5-4489-9d0b-118c3d51697d",
    "LastName": null,
    "FirstName": null,
    "City": null,
    "ZIP": null,
    "StreetAndNumber": null,
    "Active": false
}
```

Now I can't even use automapper (I guess) since I cannot navigate to say ContactPerson and map the fields to my ContactPersonDto.

I know I'm missing something here but I have 0 clue how I could deal with such columns. Probably will be running into the same problem as I progress with working on the databse.

Hope someone can lead me in the right direction on this one.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using code first or DB first? how was your entity classes generated? How does your tables look. Can you share the table diagram?

Comment: I used "Code fist from Database". The databse itself has 695 columns so the diagram is really confusing.
Since I don't need every single column, I just copy the needed columns to a new project and then work with the certain columns :|

Comment: I might be missing something here, but can't you just write a LINQ query and project it straight to a `ContactPersonDto` object?

Comment: You will need the navigation property to hold that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up your entity and relations properly to access the related data.
Add ContactPerson navigation property to ClientContactPerson class.

```
public virtual ContactPerson { get; set; }
```

Then you can eager load the data using Include().
Also set up the foreign key relation between the tables.

Comment: Aaaah thank you Harsh.
I didn't know I can just add my own navigation properties.
The generated classes were usually ok until this one so I thought there had to be another way. Thanks!

Comment: @rawk That's the beauty of code first. You've got complete control now :)